# Inversion formula as a way to check if a function is a characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Using the notion of characteristic functions from probability theory, suppose that a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is given.  Lukacs says, in his book on ch. f., that the usual inversion formula can be used to check if this function is a ch.f.  The inversion formula I know only applies to functions that are already a ch.f.  Is there a proof somewhere of why you can apply that formula to any function, and expect the result to be a probability distribution for which the ch.f. if the original function?

Answer (score 0):

We have a bounded function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$, and would like to check if it is of the form $t\mapsto \mathbf E(e^{itX})$ for some random variable $X$. There is no  memory of the original probability space $(\Omega,\nu)$ on which $X$ was defined (if it existed). The information contained in the characteristic function describes only the probability measure  $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$, namely the pushforward of $\nu$ under $X$.

Can we recover $\mu$ from $f$ by inversion? Yes, because the Fourier transform is the bijection on the space of tempered distributions. Explicitly: the functions defined by $\mathcal F^{-1}(f(t) \exp(-\epsilon t^2))$ have a distributional limit as $\epsilon\to 0$, which is $\mathcal F^{-1}f$. If the limit turns out to be a probability measure, then $f$ is its characteristic function. Otherwise not.

The above is hardly a practical way of computation, especially if $\mu$ turns out to be  singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure. There are better [criteria for being a characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Criteria_for_characteristic_functions).